# how to show eclipse console in my jsp page?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, struts2, action

I have a method in action page, it will take more time to execute so I have write some description on console window. But now i want to show the description on text area in jsp page. how to show like as console.

Comment: you mean some kind of wait/processing page?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions are the "execAndWait" interceptor and using ajax.

Execute and Wait will be the easier to implement but will present less functionality...

http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html

Ajax can provide continuous feedback of the state of the request (although managing that feedback is entirely up to you and it will typically require you to think in terms of services, one page will typically make use of multiple services).

For this you will not have to worry about the amount of time it takes your action to return because it is being called asynchronously. You could even make a queue showing how many request you've sent and pop them off as they are received.

To implement ajax services it is easiest to start with json and for that see the struts2-json-plugin http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html